# How to Import data through Panda for several years but specifc months?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas-datareader

I want to import data from panda for 10 years. But I need each season to be imported separately. for example all the data during Spring from 2000 to 2010.

I have following code but this does not separate the season.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Is there anyway ?

Comment: Import all data in one dataframe and then split it by the season.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are targeting Spring months (maybe January 1st through April 30th, subject to change), you can create a `list` of date `tuples` where each `tuple` holds the `start` and `end` dates for a given `year`. For instance, the first element of the `list` would be `(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2000, 4, 30, 0, 0))`. This would be from January 1st to April 30th in 2000.

Once you have your `list` of date `tuples`, you can iterate through them and fetch data for each combination of `start` and `end` dates. The result will also be a `list`, but this time it is going to be a `list` of `pandas` DataFrames, which you can very easily concatenate together to get your desired dataset. The following should serve as a working script:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import pandas as pd


all_dates = [(datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(year, 4, 30)) for year in range(2000, 2011)]
f = pd.concat([web.DataReader("F", 'yahoo', start, end) for start, end in all_dates], axis=1)

print(f.tail())

#             Close       Volume  Adj Close  
# Date                                       
# 2010-04-26  14.46  123029200.0  11.684445  
# 2010-04-27  13.57  292667400.0  10.965278  
# 2010-04-28  13.25  208023500.0  10.706701  
# 2010-04-29  13.58  110114400.0  10.973358  
# 2010-04-30  13.02  146322900.0  10.520849
```

I hope this helps.